# MS Reporting Services 2008 - Switch Graph from Value to Percent

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, graph

Im working with reporting services 2008 and creating a report with a table and graph data.
What i need to do, is to add a parameter, that a user can change specifying that if the results are value based or percent based.

If the user select value, the actual values in the chart and in the table appears as the real values. If the user select percent, it will appear as percent values from total.

How do i use the parameter @type i would create as input, to affect the values in the table and graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and have one table and one chart and make *everything* in them expression-based, but I think this would soon become too complex as every value would have to be nested in an `IIf` statement. Also, if you're displaying an axis on your chart, the formatting for this this is difficult to make expression-based.

I would consider including two tables and two charts in your report, designed for both value and percentage, then set the visibility for these based on your parameter, i.e. the Hidden property for the percentage items will be something like:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Type.Value = "Percentage", True, False)
```

To prevent whitespace issues, if the related objects (e.g. the two charts) are directly adjacent, i.e. no whitespace between them, SSRS generally handles this situation OK, but you may have to play around a bit.